# Take a conjunction of two hypotheses and create a new hypothesis in Coq

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I'm wondering as `destruct H as (H1 & H2).` on hypothesis `H : p /\ q` creates two hypotheses `H1 : p` and `H2 : q`, if there is any tactic that does the other way around. That is, taking two hypotheses and creating one with conjunction of those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two possibilities, using the `assert` tactic:

```
Goal forall A B : Prop, A -> B -> A /\ B.
Proof.
intros A B HA HB.
assert (H1 : A /\ B). { now split. }
assert (H2 := conj HA HB).
Abort.
```

Comment: Thanks, @Arthur Azevedo De Amorim

Comment: I hope you don't mind if I piggyback another question here. Is it possible to instantiate a variable that I introduced to my context using `exists` to a specific value? I know that for existential variable, those with names starting with `?`, you can use `instantiate` tactic but I don't know how to do it in the case I mentioned.

Comment: @DanJohnson I will gladly try to answer that when I get a chance, but in the meanwhile you're probably better off posting a separate question. Someone else might come along first and answer you! ;)